# If H and N are subgroups of G with N normal, prove that the intersection of H and N is normal in H

Tags: abstract-algebra

If H and N are subgroups of G with N normal, prove that the intersection of H and N is normal in H

I am having a bit of trouble getting started here. Clearly, H is a subgroup of G and N is a normal subgroup of G.

I think the professor may have written the problem incorrectly.

Comment: What is this "g" you refer to in the equality N={aga^-1 | a in G}? Perhaps you instead mean that aNa^-1 = N for all a in G?

Comment: @arctictern i meant to write for all a in G

Comment: I believe that the prof wrote the problem exactly right.

Comment: I also believe you might want to review the definition of a normal subgroup.

Comment: You *did* write "for all a in G." I was asking about the lowercase g.

Comment: @JohnHughes according to my book there's two definitions of normal. Either 1) it is closed with respect to conjugates or aH = Ha for all a in G.

Comment: @arctictern ahh I think I fixed that part again

Comment: Nope, still not fixed. The set {aga^-1 | for all g in G} equals all of G (for any a). The condition of normality doesn't really give us a direct way to write N using set-builder notation. Instead it simply says for all n in N and g in G, the conjugate gng^-1 is also in N.

Comment: @arctictern ahhh I see what you mean! I looked over my notes and sure enough nowhere do I have N as a set, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It is pretty premature to suspect a problem is written incorrectly with no evidence and without having tried anything at all!

Given $H,N\le G$ and $N\triangleleft G$ normal (meaning for all $n\in N$ and $g\in G$, the conjugate $gng^{-1}$ is also an element of $N$), you are trying to show $H\cap N$ is normal in $H$.

What does "$H\cap N$ is normal in $H$" mean? It means that, given $h\in H$ and $x\in H\cap N$, you want to show $hxh^{-1}\in H\cap N$.

Purely in terms of sets, in order to show something is an element of an intersection $H\cap N$, it's equivalent to showing it's an element of both sets $H$ and $N$.

Can you proceed any further from here?

Comment: Thank you! I had started in my notebook but typing from a phone it made it fairly difficult to write what I already had. The reason I stated I thought it may have been a mistake because I initially was going to prove H intersect N was a normal subgroup of G but when having read " Normal in H", it was the first time proving it about a subgroup already. The way you wrote it out allowed me to see what It is that I have to do. Thank you!